# « Jouer au piano » ou « jouer du piano » ?

Tags: usage, prépositions, musique

Doit-on utiliser *du* ou *au* pour la phrase dans le titre de cette question ? Y a-t-il une différence ?

Comment: Voir aussi [Pourquoi on joue “du” piano mais pas “de” piano?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/pourquoi-on-joue-du-piano-mais-pas-de-piano)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Jouer au piano* sonne un peu faux, sans mauvais jeu de mots. Hors de certains contextes spécifiques, cela pourrait signifier, chez un jeune enfant, quelque chose comme *jouer à faire comme si on savait jouer du piano*, ou *imiter un pianiste*. (Et cela n'impliquerait probablement même pas, en définitive, l'utilisation d'un réel piano.)

On utilisera plus couramment *jouer du piano* pour l'acte ponctuel, ou *faire du piano* pour en désigner la pratique régulière.

On pourra constater sur [ce graphe nGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jouer%20au%20piano,jouer%20du%20piano&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=) les fréquences d'usage. 
(à noter au sujet du graphe : les occurrences ici listées pour *jouer au piano*, déjà largement minoritaires, contiennent cependant, en proportions inconnues, des cas où un complément d'objet suit l'expression, comme dans *jouer au piano son morceau préféré*, ce qui est un tout autre usage que dans *Je joue au piano.*)

Comment: Est-ce que *jouer au piano* pourrais s'employer dans la même construction que *assis au piano*?

Comment: Il me semble que, sauf contexte très spécifique, ça ne serait pas clair. As-tu un exemple en tête ?

Comment: Pour la répartition des rôles, comme dans « *Ivan jouait* (ou *était*) *au piano* », ça ne me choque pas du tout.

Comment: Merci pour cet exemple de contexte spécifique permettant une exceptionnelle utilisation de l'expression. ^^

Comment: En réponse aux futures remarques du même acabit : [ceci](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jouer+au+piano%2C+jouer+du+piano&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=). Les deux usages existent, à des fréquences assez différentes cependant.

Comment: Mon Dieu, je pourrais te comprendre en français! Magnifique. Bien expliqué.

Answer (score 12):

Pour dire que quelqu'un fait de la musique avec un instrument, l'instrument est un complément d'objet direct, et l'instrument est introduit par un article partitif : *jouer du piano*, *jouer de la clarinette*, … ([TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jouer) I.F.4). Sans autre complément, *jouer à* appelle un jeu dans le sens de s'amuser (*jouer au football*, *jouer aux billes*, …), pas une production artistique.

Pour dire que quelqu'un joue un air en particulier, l'air est complément d'objet direct, et l'instrument prend la préposition *à* et un article défini : *jouer une sonate au piano, à la clarinette, ...* (TLF I.G.1.a) Pour certains instruments, on trouve aussi la préposition *sur*.

Comment: Egalement bien expliqué. Conseil utile, la partie vers un air en particulier.

Comment: A propos, j'ai posé une question spécifique sur le chat aussi.

Comment: *De* n'est pas une préposition dans ce cas. https://french.stackexchange.com/a/16947/79.

Answer (score 0):

Pour des expressions qui sont difficiles à expliquer logiquement ont a inventé
le terme gallicisme. Bien sûr, ce n'est qu'un terme spécial pour ne pas avoir à dire: On ne peut pas l'expliquer. Il y a des années que j'essaie de trouver une explication pour le "du" dans "jouer du piano". Ma seule idée: jouer de la musique en se servant du piano. Mais cela ne me convainc pas.

Comment: La réponse du petit Robert : *Jouer de (qqch)* se servir de (une chose, un instrument)  avec plus ou moins d'adresse. P.S. : on joue un morceau de musique (verbe transitif) comme on joue du Mozart ce soir à l'Opéra, mais *on ne joue pas* **de la** musique (qui est ni chose, ni instrument mais entité abstraite)