# "En jouer" ou "y" jouer .Pronoun used when talking about playing the piano

Tags: pronoms

Talking about playing the piano. Which pronoun do you use? : "j'**en** joue" ou "j'**y** joue"?

Comment: See here… https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4567/jouer-au-piano-ou-jouer-du-piano

Comment: If you have difficulty understanding the answers already given to that [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4567/jouer-au-piano-ou-jouer-du-piano), don't hesitate to leave a comment to ask for a translation of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "J'en joue".

"J'y joue" would be used for a sport or a game...

Comment: that is explainable by the concept of COD COI and circumstantial complement of place becasue can be replace before the verb but that's way to old and my memories need a refresh