# Pourquoi on joue « du » piano mais pas « de » piano ?

Tags: usage, articles

Pourquoi on dit « jouer du piano » mais pas « jouer de piano » ?

D'après [ce que je sais](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/de-vs-du-de-la-des_5.htm)), quand le nom suivant un verbe n'est pas modifié, on doit utiliser « de » seulement entre le verbe et le nom. Et « piano » n'est pas modifié, n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: ne pas prendre about.com comme référence - du moins en ce qui concerne le français. Les explications ne sont ni claires ni précises.

Comment: @Laure Merci pour le commentaire. Pourrais-je demander alors une référence de l'usage complet des articles (de, du, de la, des, de l')? Merci en tous cas.

Comment: Voir aussi [« Jouer au piano » ou « jouer du piano » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4567/jouer-au-piano-ou-jouer-du-piano)

Comment: @Gilles Merci, et je l'ai vu avant de poster cette question. Ca m'a aidé bien sûr.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pour un instrument de musique on dit bien « jouer de ». Mais c'est jouer de + l'instrument de musique **précédé de l'article défini**.

> Jouer **de la** guitare.
>   Jouer **du** piano (de+le est obligatoirement contracté en *du*).
>   Jouer **des** castagnettes. (de+les → des)

L'utilisation de *de* ou d'une autre préposition dépend du verbe ou de la locution verbale, on regarde dans un dictionnaire pour connaître la construction du verbe.

La présence de l'article défini (le, la, les) dépend de ce que l'on veut dire.

> J'ai besoin d'argent. (de l'argent en général)
>   J'ai besoin de l'argent que je t'avais prêté. (je fais référence à une somme d'argent en particulier)

Par contre jouer à + le sport ou le jeu de société précédé de l'article défini.

> Jouer au football.
>   Jouer à la belote.

Remarques par rapport au lien que tu donnes dans ta question :
*unmodified noun* est très mal expiqué.

Pour *changer*, c'est soit :

- *changer de* + nom indéfini : « changer d'avis », « changer de chemise », etc... (un autre avis, une autre chemise)
- à opposer à *changer* suivit d'un complément d'objet direct : « Il a changé l'avis qu'il s'était fait sur le copain de sa fille » (avis est précisé par la proposition relative qui suit.)

Comment: Merci pour la réponse. D'ailleurs, y-a-t-il une référence propre de la grammaire française que tu recommandes?

Comment: Sur internet je trouve [*Bonjour de France*](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/) pas mal. Ton français semble déjà excellent... si ce n'était pas le *du piano* je t'aurais cru francophone.

Comment: On a souvent des questions sur l'utilisation de *de, du, de la, des,*. Fais une recherche avec le tag [articles](http://french.stackexchange.com/tags)

Comment: C'est gentil de ta part. Et merci aussi pour la dernière suggestion, qui m'est très utile. :)

Answer (score 2):

L'explication n'est pas évidente mais elle est assez simple à comprendre quand on la connaît.

Cette construction du verbe *jouer* est transitive directe¹. On joue quelque chose (une pièce de théâtre, un morceau de musique). Pour ajouter un instrument les prépositions qu'on peut utiliser sont *avec* ou *sur* pour certains instruments. *Il a joué quelques notes sur sa guitare.* *Il joue une mélodie avec sa flûte*.
On peut aussi utiliser la préposition *à*, notamment pour indiquer une position dans un groupe ou un orchestre. *Ce jour là, exceptionnellement Ivan jouait au piano.*

Mais il se trouve qu'en français pour indiquer que quelqu'un est capable ou est en train de jouer d'un instrument on dit qu'il joue la musique de cet instrument. Et c'est exactement le sens que produit l'article partitif utilisé devant un instrument. *Du piano* signifie de la musique faite avec un piano.

> *Il joue du piano*.
>
> *Du piano parvenait jusqu'à nos oreilles.*

*Le piano* désigne dans le cas la musique d'un piano, comme dans:

> Le piano répétitif que jouait cet artiste.

Cela explique que l'on puisse aussi dire:

> Il joue un peu de piano.
>
> Il joue un piano exceptionnel.

comme on dirait *un peu de sable* ou *un sable grisâtre* avec d'autres noms indénombrables.

Dans la phrase *Je joue du piano*, *de* est un article partitif et pas une préposition comme on pourrait le croire.

—
 <sup>1. *Jouer de* existe mais a un sens différent, proche d'« utiliser » ou « tirer parti ». *Il joue de cette idée*.</sup>