# How to make a negative passive sentence?

Tags: négation, passif

Where do we put the "ne ... pas" in a negative passive sentence?

For example, for

> Le chat attrape la souris.

the passive would be

> La souris est attrapée par le chat.

What if I want to say “Le chat n'attrape pas la souris”. How to make the passive voice?

And what about other tenses (especially compound ones)?

Comment: You should write one question per topic,  one about the negative, and the other about reflexive verbs, even if  the passive is concerned in both questions, it is not sufficient to merge questions & answers.

Comment: Jouer **du**  piano. [See](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/11875/358). The fact that it is a passive voice has no influence on the negative, you still have to place the negation on each side of the auxiliary (here *être*).  [See](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/exercices/contenu/12/grammaire/159.html).

Comment: Not all verbs can be in the passive voice, which is the case for *se souvenir* (if my memory does not  fail me).

Comment: Please ask about passive voice for pronominal verbs in a separate question.

Comment: *Je joue du piano* does't have a passive counterpart, because in French the piano doesn't occupy a direct objet position. I changed the example for one that permits passive voice.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez but *jouer du piano* can be in used in the passive voice - it's just a matter of no agent being given.  [*lorsque le piano est joué*](http://www.pianosperrard.com/#!accord/yvbx8), [*le piano est joué quotidiennement*](http://www.arpege-piano.net/fr/conservation-piano-entretien.html), etc.

Comment: @Laure: Où as tu lu ou entendu ça? C'est grammaticalement incorrect, et me parait complètement artificiel. On joue une pièce ou une musique, mais pas un instrument.

Comment: @Laure: Actually *du piano est joué* is correct (refering to piano music), but this is an overly complicated example.

Answer (score 3):

The negative form of a passive sentence obeys the same rule as when the verb is not in its *[infinitif](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitif)* form  and is *[composé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temps_compos%C3%A9)* which thing means the negation ***ne ... pas*** must wrap the [*auxiliaire*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbe_auxiliaire).

- Le chat attrape la souris  ⇒ La souris **n**'est **pas** attrapée par le chat
- Le chat attrapait la souris ⇒ La souris **n**'était **pas** attrapée par le chat
- Le chat attrapera la souris ⇒ La souris **ne** sera **pas** attrapée par le chat

Answer (score 1):

In all two-verb forms(1) *ne* precedes the first verb and *pas* follows it.

*La souris n'est pas attrapée*

*Je ne suis pas monté*

*Elle n'aura pas terminé*

(1) Including both [helping verb](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/auxiliary-verbs/) + [past participle](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/past-participle/) (passive voice, passé composé, and all compound tenses/moods) as well as [semi-auxiliary verb](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/semi-auxiliary-verbs/) + [infinitive](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/infinitive/) (je ne veux pas aller, il n'aime pas danser, etc)