# Changing the articles when forming a negative sentence

Tags: grammaire, articles

When forming a negative sentence that contains the verb "jouer" + musical instrument, such as:

> Je joue de la guitare

do we change the article "de la" → "de" or do we keep it unchanged?

Comment: Cf. http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/pourquoi-on-joue-du-piano-mais-pas-de-piano

Answer (score 3):

While the rule is to drop the article in the negative forms, musical instruments are an exception so the correct sentence is always:

> Je ne joue pas **de la** guitare.

which is the negation of

> Je joue **de la** guitare.

With a different verb, that would be:

> Je vends **une** guitare/**des** guitares (unlikely *je vends **de la** guitare* unless an informal statement by a wholesaler)

and their negation would be;

> Je ne vends pas **de** guitare.

---

Reference: [Académie Française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#64_strong-em-partitif-et-dterminant-em-strong):

> N.B. : Il en va différemment de **jouer** de suivi du nom d’un instrument de musique : l’instrument sera **toujours** introduit par un déterminant : Je joue (ne joue pas) du piano ; Je joue (ne joue pas) de l’orgue ; Je joue (ne joue pas) des castagnettes, de la clarinette.

Answer (score 2):

Considering this sentence :

> Je joue **de la** guitare.

*De la* is a [partitive article](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-54173.php). Is is used for sports and music instruments (check out the link for some examples - sentences and negative form !).

**Additionally to what the article says, the right way to build the negative form actually depends on what you are going to answer.**

1. You are not playing the guitar (as a habit, you don't *know* how to play the guitar), or you are not playing the guitar at the moment you're speaking. De :

> Je ne joue pas **de** guitare.

Indeed, the article *la* disappears !

2. You are not playing the guitar, but you are playing the violin !

> Je ne joue pas **de la** guitare, je joue du violon !

On that particular case, you want to keep the *la*.

Comment: I would add that _je ne joue pas de guitare_ sounds strange to me. It might not be very used in practice.

Comment: Really ? Not only this is the right grammatical rule, but also (for me at least) the most natural way to say this. _Je ne joue pas de la guitare_ stated alone sounds really clumsy.

Comment: Je crois que naturellement j'utiliserais une autre tournure. Je ne dis pas que c'est faux, juste que pour moi ça sonne un peu bizarre. Qu'est-ce que ça donne avec d'autres instruments, par exemple, _piano_, ... ?